# Diminuir o uso de memória de funções recursivas no PHP

Tags: php, funções, memória

Tenho uma função recursiva no PHP onde ela faz um loop numa api onde a mesma apenas permite que você recupere 200 registos da mesma por vez.

Porém como essa API tem uma latência muito alta de resposta decidimos usar um banco de dados intermediário local onde eu adiciono esses registos e o mesmo será mostrado no site.

Porém como essa API possui mais de 30 mil registos a função recursiva ela consome muita memória devido que ela no caso de 30 mil registos ela teria que ser invocada recursivamente mais de 1500 vezes e isso acaba dando o famoso StackOverflow.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma manual de limpar a memória dessa função chamando-a novamente sem perder o valor da mesma.

Exemplo do código:

```
public function recursive($index = 0, $offset = 200){
   $api = getConectApi($index,offset)->getRecords();
   foreach($api as $value){
      //aqui ocorre meu loop necessário
   }
   if(count($api) > 0){
     $this->recursive($index+200,$offset+200);
   }
}
```

Gostaria de encontrar uma forma que quando chamasse a função recursiva novamente eliminasse o alocação anterior sem perder o valor de referência que foi passado.

Comment: Pessoal obrigado a todos que responderam e tentaram ajudar. Mas no stackoverflow em inglês já me deram uma solução boa para o problema, caso alguém esteja passando pelo mesmo problema só acessar o link abaixo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429216/decrease-memory-usage-of-recursive-functions-in-php?noredirect=1#comment79818427_46429216 Obrigado à todos pela ajuda!